# How can I tansfer data from thanos into cnosdb?

Tags: cnosdb, thanos

Thanos is high-available monitoring system based on promethues. but thanos is too heavry, i want to use cnosdb to boost useness of our sre observility tools. So How can I tansfer thanos data into cnosdb with zero-downtime? what's is advantage of cnosdb over thanos?